# Java question on runtime type checking in implemented method

Tags: java, oop, design-patterns

I am designing some java objects to represent graphs and trees. For my use case I will be using both data types but I also want my graph algorithms to work on my trees.

```
import java.util.List;

public interface Node<T> {
    T getValue();
    List<? extends Node<T>> getNeighbors();
    void addNodes(List<? extends Node<T>> nodes);
}

public interface TreeNode<T> extends Node<T> {
    List<? extends TreeNode<T>> getChildren();
    void addChildren(List<? extends TreeNode<T>> treeNodes);

    @Override
    default List<? extends Node<T>> getNeighbors() {
        return getChildren();
    }

    @Override
    default void addNodes(List<? extends Node<T>> nodes) {
        if(nodes.getClass().isInstance(getChildren().getClass())) {
            addChildren((List<? extends TreeNode<T>>) nodes);
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("Type error!");
        }
    }
}
```

My question is about how I'm dealing with addNodes method in the Node interface in the TreeNode interface. The addNodes method has to be in the Node interface because I want to allow people to write code that can add nodes to graphs. However, I also don't want people to add arbitrary nodes to a tree node(for example adding a graph node to a tree node).

In order to prevent this, I'm checking the type of nodes at runtime and throwing an exception if the type is not right. I'm just wondering if this is the best way to accomplish what I want or if there is a better practice?

Thanks for helping :)

Comment: I do not understand the distinction between a `Node` and a `TreeNode` in your code.

Comment: The way I see it, `Node` is a container for some data. `Tree` and `Graph` are two ways to maintain relationships between Nodes. So perhaps three classes should be defined that represent this design

Comment: @AdamSiemion Node is a graph node, TreeNode is a tree node

Comment: @SharonBenAsher Can you please elaborate a little bit?

Comment: `nodes.getClass()` as you have it will never work, because `getClass()` always returns the *runtime* type, which will be the erasure of the actual parameterized type. So the classes will compare the same regardless of the subtypes of the nodes. If you want to check the types of the values in the list, you'll need to take a `Class` object for the element type, e.g. `Class<Node>`; there is no such thing as a `Class<List<Node>>` due to erasure.

Comment: @DanielPryden Thanks for the reminder. How would you recommend I go about this? There's no guarantees that the nodes will not be an empty list.

Comment: @Jessica: I would recommend not trying to check the type at runtime. Instead just use a more sophisticated generic type to ensure type safety at compile time, which appears to be possible here. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, what you want is (a variation on) the so-called [curiously recurring template pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern). The `Node` type needs to be parameterized not only by its payload type (T) but also by the type of nodes it can be used with. So you want something like:

```
public interface Node<T, N extends Node<T, N>> {
    T getValue();
    List<N> getNeighbors();
    void addNodes(List<N> nodes);
}

public interface TreeNode<T> extends Node<T, TreeNode<T>> {
    List<TreeNode<T>> getChildren();
    void addChildren(List<TreeNode<T>> treeNodes);

    @Override
    default List<TreeNode<T>> getNeighbors() {
        return getChildren();
    }

    @Override
    default void addNodes(List<TreeNode<T>> nodes) {
        addChildren(nodes);
    }
}
```

Demo (shows compilation only): https://ideone.com/44qrmX

Comment: Is there a way to accomplish the same thing without requiring people to specify N?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately. But if the client code works directly with concrete subtypes like `TreeNode` then there won't be any need to name the type of N explicitly.

Comment: Would it be possible to write code that operates on this Node interface directly? I don't think it's possible. One of the use cases I wanted to capture was writing code for Node and reusing it for the TreeNode

Comment: Sure, you just need to use a wildcard type for N. Something like `Node<Integer, ?>` will allow you to call `getValue()` in a typesafe way. You won't be able to *add* nodes into it, but that's correct, because if you only have a `Node` then you don't know the right kind of nodes to add as its children.

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, `Node` is a container for some data. `Tree` and `Graph` are two ways to maintain relationships between Nodes. So perhaps three classes should be defined:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Node<T> {
    private T value;
    public Node(T value) { this.value = value; }
    T getValue() { return value; }
}

public abstract class Tree<T> {
    private Node<T> root;

    public abstract List<? extends Node<T>> getChildren();
    public abstract void addChildren(List<? extends Node<T>> nodes);

    public Tree(Node<T> root) { this.root = root; }
}

public abstract class Graph<T> {
    private Node<T> root;

    public abstract List<? extends Node<T>> getNeighbors();
    public abstract void addNeighbors(List<? extends Node<T>> nodes);

    public Graph(Node<T> root) { this.root = root; }
}
```

**EDIT**: If you want to have shared traversal algorithms, you can put them in separate classes and have the Tree and Graph use similar semantics like this:

```
// common semantics for node containers
public interface NodeContainer<T> {
    List<? extends Node<T>> getRelatedNodes();
}

public abstract class Tree<T> implements NodeContainer<T> {

    ...  // same as above

    @Override
    public List<? extends Node<T>> getRelatedNodes() {
        return getChildren();
    }
}

public class NodeContainerTraversal {

    public void bfs (NodeContainer<?> container) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is: If I write a BFS for Graph class, I can't use it on the tree class.

Comment: so really what's the difference between tree and graph? is it only semantics?

Comment: When someone uses a TreeNode, there's an assumption that that node satisfies tree property. Ie no circles in that tree. When someone uses a regular Node that assumption is not there